# I need to ask a REALLY general C# question, but I don't want to break protocol

Tags: discussion

So I'm trying to merge Word Docs from a Doc set.  I've found this code [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff519529%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
Its replicated throughout the web.

THis adds a webpart to a Sharepoint page, on the webpart is a button that fires some c# code.  I've gotten the part that draws the button and calls the next part of code built, but the first line of the next part of code

```
   SPFolder folder = SPContext.Current.ListItem.Folder;
```

crashes on a Null Listitem.

So the question I have is, *"how do I make this work?"*

Problem is, that looks a lot like "*Write this for me please*"

I've tried asking very specific questions, but its like "Why is this null?" ..."Well, because it contains no data.  Your welcome" .

I really don't mind doing exhaustive trial & error, but I need some help asking the right question(s).
It just seems that "what's the best way to loop through all docs in a folder" is too general.

So what's a novice programmer-thief to do?

Comment: @Sergio A very very careful reading of this suggests they're asking *how* to ask this question

Comment: @RichardTingle, thanks. Just wanted to help him before he is shotdown with downvotes. Was too fast, and wrong.

Comment: One point; if there is a null listitem then there is a null list. If this is the first line of the code you're executing and the other part builds your list then your problem is not with the posted code... before posting a question go back and look over how your list is being created... if you still can't work it out then post what you have as an explanation _then_ show how your list is being created and the steps you've taken to debug, including everything you've ruled out already.

Comment: Isn't this a place to get some help in the "what's ok, what's not" and "how do I properly axe a question" place?

Comment: `So what's a novice programmer-thief to do?`  Don't dual-class, it takes *forever* to gain levels.  Seriously though, post the code, post the *exact* error, and post what you've tried to do to debug it.

Comment: OK...should I axe it here or over in the regular S.O. site?

Comment: @jazaddict Definitely on the regular S.O site

Comment: On regular SO, of course.  Here is fine for asking about asking; but don't actually ask.  :)

Comment: Aight....off I go. Thx fellas.

Comment: One more thing....what do I do with the 2 questions I've asked that more-or-less went nowhere and are prolly useless?

Comment: @jazaddict Good luck, try to include a complete (but short as possible) code snippet in the question that demostrates the problem

Comment: @jazaddict If you don't care about them; leave them, they may be answered on day. If you do care about them; edit them to make them cleared etc or (if you have the rep) put a bounty on them

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929541/why-is-spcontext-current-listitem-null) is your original question.  Edit that question rather than reposting, as it looks like that's just a somewhat poor attempt at asking it because you don't provide enough context around the question.

Answer (score 3):

In general your initial instinct seems about right, to me.  I would ask the question like so:

- I have a blah blah blah.  I am trying to blah blah blah.
- When I try to add a new document, it crashes (blah error message).
- How do I instantiate a new ListItem such that this does not occur?

Something like that (without the bullets and blahs) is a good question - which is very similar to your question.  That question isn't really asking 'gimme teh codes' so much as 'erm, what am I doing wrong'.  Especially if you are very specific and post enough of your own code to make it clear you are doing the work.  If the answer is hundreds of lines of code, you'll find out in comments/answers.

Comment: Did someone just say "[blah blah blah](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3taEuL4EHAg)!?"

Comment: No, I just have a 2 year old at home :)